# using local modules with npm-container

Tags: meteor, npm

I'm try to integrate a local node modules in my app running on meteor with npm-container https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm
It does not seems to be possible. I try to use "name":"file:path-to-local-module" but npm-container  require to specify the version.
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your meteor version to the 1.3 beta version using the command

```
meteor update --release 1.3-beta.12
```

Then you won't need the meteorhacks package to add npm modules.
Basically this will install a new package called 'modules' that will take care of bundling all the js.

As per the [README](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.3/packages/modules/README.md) says:

> Before Meteor 1.3, the contents of node_modules directories in Meteor
>   application code were completely ignored. When you enable modules,
>   those useless node_modules directories suddenly become infinitely more
>   useful:

```
meteor create modular-app 
cd modular-app 
mkdir node_modules 
npm install moment 
echo 'import moment from "moment";' >> modular-app.js 
echo 'console.log(moment().calendar());' >> modular-app.js 
meteor
```